# Wix install location appearing incorrectly as command line argument

Tags: directory, wix, installation, command-line-arguments

I'm attempting to create an installer with wix, and I want it to behave in such a way that when the short cut is selected, it passes the install file to my programs args[], for it to use a path to execute a file.
However, I have added a few logs, and noticed that for some reason the path it is receiving is "C:\Program". I cannot get this to appear differently, even if I manually set the arguments to be the full path. Here's some snippets of the .wxs file.

```
<!-- Define directory structure -->
    <Directory Id ="TARGETDIR" Name ="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id ="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id ="MyAppsFolder" Name ="Applications">
                <Directory Id ="INSTALLFOLDER" Name ="MyApp">
                </Directory>
                <Directory Id ="ProgramMenuFolder">
                    <Directory Id ="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="Example Folder">
                        <Directory Id ="ShortcutFolder" Name ="MyApp">
                        </Directory>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

<!-- Creating the shortcut -->
    <DirectoryRef Id ="ShortcutFolder">
        <Component Id ="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="{GUID_HERE}">
            <Shortcut Id ="RunMyApp"
                                Name ="MyApp"
                                Description ="Runs MyApp"
                                Target ="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyApp.exe"
                                WorkingDirectory ="INSTALLFOLDER"
                                Icon ="MyApp.ico"
                                Arguments ="[INSTALLFOLDER]FileToLoad.xml"/>
```

The [INSTALLFOLDER] seems to work for everything else but this last line in the arguments.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a well-known behavior, WiX doesn't know what your arguments are then it doesn't quote them. Note that `[INSTALLFOLDER]` will be expanded during installation to (for example) `c:\program files\your app`, it's like you execute your application from command line with this syntax:

```
MyApp c:\program files\your app
```

Note that your application will have `{ "c:\\program", "files\\your", "app" }`.

Just quote your path explicitly:

```
<Shortcut Id ="RunMyApp"
    Name ="MyApp"
    Description ="Runs MyApp"
    Target ="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyApp.exe"
    WorkingDirectory ="INSTALLFOLDER"
    Icon ="MyApp.ico"
    Arguments ="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]FileToLoad.xml&quot;"/>
```

It'll result in `"c:\program files\your app\FileToLoad.xml"` and command line parser will recognize it as a single argument. Note `&quot;` character entity reference, for a complete list you may refer to [List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Comment: Thank you! I've only discovered wix in the past few days so I wasn't aware. I had a hunch it was to do with quotations but I didn't know to format them in this way.

Comment: @Stinkidog it's plain _unfriendly_ ;) XML, see this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 0):

I've found that by remove the [INSTALLFOLDER], it worked just fine. The line now looks like this:

```
Arguments ="[INSTALLFOLDER]FileToLoad.xml"/>
```

I have noticed it may be because the working directory is already set to INSTALLFOLDER, although I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, it's because of `[INSTALLFOLDER]`, see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31401508/1207195). It contains spaces and when expanded all string will be passed _as-is_ to your application, its command line parser will then split that long text to `string[]` using spaces as delimiters.